# Understanding the idea behind the super-Poincaré algebra

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

On the Super-poincaré algebra wiki page ([https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincaré_algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra)), it says:

"If Minkowski space-time belongs to the adjoint representation, then can Poincaré symmetry be extended to the fundamental representation? Well, it can: this is exactly the super-Poincaré algebra. There is a corresponding experimental question: if we live in the adjoint representation, then where is the fundamental representation hiding? This is the program of supersymmetry, which has not been found experimentally."

What does it mean for minkowski space to belong to the adjoint rep? And for the poincaré symmetry to extend to the fundamental rep? What rep is it in prior?

I think this could be a super neat understanding of the concept but I cant seem to make sense of it or find any other content using this description.

Comment: What is meant is that the Lorentz group can be represented by SL$(2,\mathbb{C})$ matrices, which acts on Weyl spinors. Then the vector representation can be obtained by writing $x_{\alpha\dot\alpha}=x_\mu\sigma^\mu_{\alpha\dot\alpha}$ to see that under a Lorentz transformation $x_{\alpha\dot\alpha}\mapsto U_\beta{}^\alpha\,U_{\dot\beta}{}^{\dot\alpha} \,x_{\alpha\dot\alpha}$. Here you can argue that $x$ transforms in the adjoint representation (even though I personally would not use this term). This can be extended to the Poincaré algebra, and then leads to the superspace coordinates $\theta$.